# Function to be used by others - how to export so that code isn't exposed

Tags: java

I wrote some code in java and I want to have it to be an exe file or any other form of user interface for other developers to use it

EDIT
what I have used in the end was exporting to jar as user  user85421 suggested.

Comment: What specifically do you want to achieve? "I need a UI" is pretty un-specific. Please elaborate on what you want to do and where exactly you have problems. We don´t even know what kind of UI you´re after? web-app? native app? console? ...?

Comment: Your question is too general. You can try to use Swing, may be good for a start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: What do you mean by "like an exe file"? How is it related to the UI? "exe" files can work in a terminal as well

Comment: Please give more context on "the function to be executed". Where does this code live? What kind of input and output does it expect/produce? And most important: what did you try yourself?

Comment: You can compile your program with `javac` and your "exe" would be just a bash script with the following line `java MainClass.class`

Comment: create a JAR, or, if using recent version of Java, just include something like `#!/path/to/java --source 13` at the beginning of the source file and rename it to some name **not** ending with `*.java` ([JEP 330](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330#Shebang_files))

Answer (score 2):

The default GUI classes of Java are called Swing. You should buy a book about Swing or take a look at any tutorial like this: https://www.guru99.com/java-swing-gui.html

If text-only input and output is OK, then just use the classes `Scanner` and `System`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers:");
        int number1=scanner.nextInt();
        int number2=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d\n", number1, number2, number1+number2);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Enter two numbers:
3
4
3 + 4 = 7
```